# How js router works to specify parameter with pure js?

Tags: javascript

I have route like this

```
/index
/control/action/:param1
/control/action/:param1/edit/:param2/:nullparam?
```

And I have path like this

```
/control/action/profile/edit/yoza
```

I have 2 question : 
with pure js how to specify/read that path is for the third route

```
/control/action/:param1/edit/:param2/:nullparam?
```

how to convert this path to js object by route like this :

```
{ param1 : 'profile', param2 : 'yoza' , nullparam :null}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether or not you are using the hash `/#/pathhere` address or a regular `/pathhere` address, the raw path is accessible via `location.hash` or `location.pathname`

I wrote a simple router a while ago. See below: (it probably needs to be refined but should work in most cases)

The general algorithm is to split both the pattern (spec for the path) and the current path the browser is on separately by '/' marks and compare individual components (extracting when needed).

Alternatively, some routers may convert the pattern to a regex and use regular express capture groups to accomplish the same thing

```
// splits a path nicely by '/' characters
function splitpath(path){
    if(!path)
        return [];

    var arr = path.split('/');
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i].trim().length === 0){
            arr.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

// Given a path and its pattern, try to parse it into list of parameters (or NULL if it can't be parsed)
// i.e  parsepath('/r/hello' '/r/:room') should return { room: 'hello' }
function parsepath(path, pattern){

    path = splitpath(path), pattern = splitpath(pattern);

    var params = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++){

        if(pattern[i].charAt(0) == ':'){ // Capture group
            var name = pattern[i].slice(1);
            var optional = false;
            if(name.charAt(name.length - 1) == '?'){
                optional = true;
                name = name.slice(0, name.length - 1);
            }
            if(!optional && path.length <= i){
                // Missing mandatory param
                return null;
            }

            if(path.length <= i)
                params[name] = null; // Set to null for a missing optional param
            else 
              params[name] = decodeURIComponent(path[i]);
        }
        else{ // Matching pattern
            if(pattern[i] != path[i])
                return null;
        }
    }

    return params;
}

console.log(parsepath(
'/control/action/profile/edit/yoza/abc',
'/control/action/:param1/edit/:param2/:nullparam?'))
```